# How to know if any row of a table satisfies a condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am executing a CodeIgniter statement to select a row from a table with the following query:

```
$result = $this->db->query('select * from table_name where cond1 and cond2);
```

But how will I know any row is selected or not. I have used count($result) to determine the number of rows selected. But it is returning 1 in both the cases i.e. when a row satisfies the conditions and when no row does not satisfy the condition. So I am asking whether there is any way to check that. Thank you.

Here assume that there can be only one row present with satisfying cond1 and cond2.

Comment: ur checking with both cases using and so it shows record when both cases satisfy ..instead of and use or..$result = $this->db->query('select * from table_name where (cond1) or (cond2));...then it will check cond1 or cond2

Comment: @nickle I have just given the query as a sample. Actually I want to know how determine if any row is selected by the select statement.

Comment: What extension are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: in codeigniter you need to do `count($result->rows)`

Comment: mysql -h localhost -u username -ppassword -Ddatabasename ;

Comment: What for do you need that number?

Comment: @DevZer0 I have used $result->rows as you suggested. But it is giving the following error: Message:  Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$rows

Comment: @Joy try `echo $result->num_rows`

Answer (score 1):

```
if($result->num_rows()>0){
    //One or more rows satisfies the condition
}else {
    //Zero rows satisfies the condition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You looking for this?

```
$result ->num_rows();
```

Comment: It is doing the same. For example, there is only one row present in the database satisfying both cond1 and cond2. But when no row is present, it is also giving 1.

Comment: Can you paste your conditions here. Or add link to screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

$result = $this->db->query('select count(*) from table_name where cond1 and cond2');

then you need to extract the count from the first column of the returned row.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/codeigniter/database/DB_result.php.source.html#line35) the correct answer is `echo $result->num_rows;`

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see how your full query is written, put in two where clauses like this and it binds them with AND:

```
           $this->db
           ->select ('*')
           ->from('table_name')
           ->where('table_name.column', cond1)
           ->where('table_name.column2', cond2);

$result = $this->db->get();
if ($result) {
//this means you have results, do something with them here
}

$count = $result->num_rows();

OR

$count = count($result->result());
```